# "Must be defined" Parametro no definido en consulta Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Voy a realizar un update en un formulario con Vb.Net y Mysql, pero me tira el error siguiente "`Parameter ?nombre_lugar WHERE must be defined`" y bueno no permite editar

Esta es mi consulta;

```
Dim connstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("db").ConnectionString
Dim txt_id_lugar = CType(editableItem.FindControl("txt_id_lugar"), TextBox)
Dim txt_nombre_lugar = CType(editableItem.FindControl("txt_nombre_lugar"), TextBox)
Dim lbl_error = CType(editableItem.FindControl("lblErr1"), Label)

sqlQuery = "UPDATE t_salas set nombre_lugar = ?nombre_lugar"
sqlQuery = sqlQuery & "WHERE id_lugar=?id_lugar"
myconn = New MySqlConnection(connstr)

myconn.Open()
    mycommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, myconn)
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id_lugar", txt_id_lugar.Text)
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre_lugar", txt_nombre_lugar.Text)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué complicarse, cuando puedes escribir la consulta así: **`sqlQuery = "UPDATE t_salas set nombre_lugar = ?nombre_lugar WHERE id_lugar=?id_lugar"`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error era que ocurria lo siguiente, se pegaba el parametro y el WHERE forMando una sola palabra y bueno le di espacio tal cual y funciono :/

```
`?nombre_lugarWHERE`     ------>    `?nombre_lugar WHERE`
//El espacio entre lugar y WHERE

sqlQuery = "UPDATE t_salas set nombre_lugar =?nombre_lugar WHERE id_lugar=?id_lugar"
```

Comment: Excelente, muy bien por haber encontrado el inconveniente, pero no te sorprendas si tu pregunta es cerrada, ya que la podrian considerar como un error tipografico.